# Remove Tabs Within Remark

Tags: sed

i would like to remove the tabs within the comments, such as this sample;

```
<?php

                    //this is a comment with tab
$tes = 1;
$this->HTTP_URL = str_replace('///', '//', $this->http.$this->serverName.$this->port.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
if ($tes == 1) {
    //this is a comment with tab
    echo $tes;
}

            //this is a comment with tab
$tes = 2;
```

I've tested it with;

> sed -e 's|/*.**/||g' -e 's|//.*||g' test.php > test2.php

But the result is;

```
this is a comment with tab
$tes = 1;
', $this->http.$this->serverName.$this->port.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
if ($tes == 1) {
this is a comment with tab
    echo $tes;
}

this is a comment with tab
$tes = 2;
```

I want it to look like;

```
//this is a comment with tab
$tes = 1;
$this->HTTP_URL = str_replace('///', '//', $this->http.$this->serverName.$this->port.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
if ($tes == 1) {
//this is a comment with tab
    echo $tes;
}

//this is a comment with tab
$tes = 2;
```

or even better with

```
/* this is a comment with tab */
$tes = 1;
$this->HTTP_URL = str_replace('///', '//', $this->http.$this->serverName.$this->port.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
if ($tes == 1) {
/* this is a comment with tab */
    echo $tes;
}

/* this is a comment with tab */
$tes = 2;
```

I've tried various way, yet still have not come to the result i wanted.
Thank you.

....

i've tried with

```
gsed -i 's|^\s*//|//|' test.php
```

and then

```
gsed -i ':a;$!{N;ba};s/^/\x00/;tb;:b;s/\x00$//;t;s/\x00\(\/\*[^*]*\*\+\([^/*][^*]*\*\+\)*\/\)/\1\x00/;tb;s/\x00\/\/\([^\n]*\)/\/*\1\*\/\x00/;tb;s/\x00\(.\)/\1\x00/;tb' test.php
```

but the result is

```
<?php

/*this is a comment with tab*/
$tes = 1;
$this->HTTP_URL = str_replace('/*/', '//', $this->http.$this->serverName.$this->port.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);*/
if ($tes == 1) {
/*this is a comment with tab*/
    echo $tes;
}

/*this is a comment with tab*/
$tes = 2;
```

notice the error line 4

```
$this->HTTP_URL = str_replace('/*/', '//', $this->http.$this->serverName.$this->port.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);*/
```

it should not be replaced. need another syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i 's|^\s*//|//|' file
```

This removes zero or more spaces or tabs (white space) from the start of lines whose first two non-white space characters are `//`.

If it is only tabs you want removed:

```
sed -i s|^\t*//|//|' file
```

N.B. This may substitute nothing for nothing i.e. a line beginning with `//` will still effect a substitution so the last solution should be:

```
sed -i 's|^\t\+//|//|' file
```

EDIT:

```
sed -i 's|^\t\+//\(.*\)$|/*\1*/' file
```

Or change `//` regardless:

```
sed -i 's|^\t\+//|//|;s|//\(.*\)|/*\1*/|' file
```

Comment: sorry, error from your command line, my filename is test.php.
> sed: 1: "test.php": undefined label 'est.php'

Comment: after removing the -i, all your command return the same as before. sorry

Comment: after installing GNU sed with `brew install gnu-sed` your solutions work fine. thanks.

Comment: hi @potong, i have another request to replace // with /* (remark statement) */ thanks

Comment: @rezashamdani see EDIT.

Comment: error: gsed: -e expression #1, char 23: unterminated `s' command

Comment: error too in 2nd edit: gsed: -e expression #1, char 3: unterminated `s' command

Comment: dear @potong, this `gsed -i 's|^\s\+//\(.*\)$|/* \1 */|' test.php` works. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/^[[:space:]]*\/\//{s/^[[:space:]]*//}' yourfile.php
```

should do it. If you wish to do an infile edit, do

```
sed -i~ '/^[[:space:]]*\/\//{s/^[[:space:]]*//}' yourfile.php
```

A backup of the original file starting with <kbd>~</kbd> will be created.

Comment: sorry, error return from your command:
>sed: 1: "/^[[:space:]]*\/\//{s/^ ...": bad flag in substitute command: '}'

Comment: @rezashamdani What platform? Is  `-i` supported in your `sed`?

Comment: sorry. you solutions works fine too, but @potong who pointed me out to use the GNU sed. thanks.